# How do I remove Pandas irrelevant out information?

Tags: python

Why in my output when I have execute only the number but the output is coming as shown below

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'test':[200, 300]})
print(df['test'][df['test']==200])
```

```sh
0        200 

Name: Value, dtype : float64
```

and when I making dataframe from this even Name: Value, dtype : float 64 is coming in my dataframe even I have not called. I want only 200 to come in my dataframe

How do I return just `200`?

Comment: Include a minimal reproducible example (e.g, code someone can run by itself to see your issue) and what you expect to see.  Right now we have to guess.

Comment: please share more information on your question

Answer (score 0):

Set index=False

Here 0 is the index column.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are returning a `Pandas` series and not a value. You can use `.loc` or `.iloc` to get the value.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'test':[200, 300]})

# print the value at index 0
print(df['test'].iloc[0]) # 200
```

Or you can use `.values`

```py
# values return an `array([200, 300])`
print(df['test'].values[0]) # 200
```

You can see the type of the return results with `type`

```py
print(type(df['test'])) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(df['test'].values[0])) # <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

The series will return the index and datatype